# Error thrown when attempting to enter "Explore" mode of Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

The following wonderful error is thrown when I try to enter "Explore" mode in the Experience Editor.

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: view]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext..ctor(ControllerContext controllerContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TempDataDictionary tempData, TextWriter writer) +326
   Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.Mvc.RenderPageExtenders.InjectExperienceExplorerControl.RenderPartial(String partialName, Object model, TextWriter writer) +463
   Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.Mvc.RenderPageExtenders.InjectExperienceExplorerControl.Render(TextWriter writer) +293
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderPageExtendersProcessor.Process(RenderPageExtendersArgs args) +65
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.GetExtendersHtml() +158
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.get_ExtendersHtml() +31
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Request.RequestEnd.AddPageExtenders.Process(RequestEndArgs args) +200
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +135
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
```

The page displays okay when I am in "Edit" or "Preview" mode.

I am using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: We'll need more details. Have you installed any Sitecore module, is there any custom pipeline, rendering, or customization? Is there any js error logged in your browser?

Comment: Plenty of modules.   No javascript error.  I do note that the url loaded is `about/executive-team?sc_mode=normal&sc_debug=0&sc_trace=0&sc_prof=0&sc_ri=0&sc_rb=0&sc_expview=1`    (why is the sc_mode=normal, shouldn't it be explore or something?)

Comment: I also note these two lines in console.   `Failed to call scGetFrameValue in IFrame tag. This typically happens due to a Permission Denied exception in IE9 caused by an intricate issue with Popup and ShowModalDialog calls. Blocked a frame with origin "https://stage.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`
and `ExperienceEditor.js:672 ApplicationCache is not declared.`

Comment: @eat-sleep-code looks like Sitecore also got carried away with their querystrings, but &sc_expview=1 is what is triggering the experience explorer to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've actually seen this issue before.  It is caused when the view `ExperienceExplorerView.cshtml` doesn't exist in the your /Views/Shared folder in your website root.

To fix this, just make sure you drop a copy of that file from a fresh install into this folder.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, I would suggest you explore more the log that you found in your browser's console:

> Failed to call scGetFrameValue in IFrame tag. This typically happens
>   due to a Permission Denied exception in IE9 caused by an intricate
>   issue with Popup and ShowModalDialog calls. Blocked a frame with
>   origin "https://stage.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin
>   frame. and ExperienceEditor.js:672 ApplicationCache is not declared.

I've found the following article on Sitecore KB "[Experience Editor not functioning properly on the pages with jQuery](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/286042)" where the message you got is mentioned in this article.

Their proposed solution is in order to avoid editing issues in Experience Editor use jQuery JavaScript library in the No-Conflict mode. Please check the following article for details:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

With regards to the question:

> Plenty of modules. No javascript error. I do note that the url loaded
>   is
>   about/executive-team?sc_mode=normal&sc_debug=0&sc_trace=0&sc‌​_prof=0&sc_ri=0&sc_r‌​b=0&sc_expview=1
>   (why is the sc_mode=normal, shouldn't it be explore or something?)

Yes, it is correct. 
I've just installed a new Sitecore 8.2 instance and here is the URL it gives me when in Explore mode:

*SITECORE_URL*?**sc_mode=normal**&sc_itemid={110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}&sc_version=1&sc_lang=en&sc_site=website&sc_debug=0&sc_trace=0&sc_prof=0&sc_ri=0&sc_rb=0&**sc_expview=1**

And here is what the browser logs in the console in a new Sitecore instance:

[image]